# Why notifyDataSetChanged() scrolls the ListView up android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I searched absolutely everything, but all the solutions from the sources did not help.

When notifyDataSetChanged() is called, the BaseAdapter — ListView adapter starts scrolling to where new elements have been added. How to remove scrolling? How to make a "quiet" addition of elements so that nothing scrolls. The user must scroll to the desired location by himself.

P.S. scrolls up if you add items to the beginning of the LinkedList. When elements are added to the end, this is not observed.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_below="@id/chat_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/chat_bottom"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:id="@+id/messages_list"
/>
```

Comment: Get the listviews scrolling/first visible position before calling notifyDataSetChanged(). Then after it set the position back.

Comment: @blackapps, I understand that like this?
 int position = messagesList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
messagesList.setSelection(position);

Comment: listView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(); ?

Comment: Stop using ListView and use RecyclerView so that you can use notifyItemInserted instead of notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: @Tyczj, Let's say I have a chat. There are three types of messages: 1) service (only text in the center), 2) outgoing (right), 3) incoming (left). How do I properly make an inflater in a RecyclerView depending on the conditions received from the message object?